# MongoDate comparision for date only

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

Hi guys I am new to mongodb and facing some problem while comparing dates in my collection. I have a collection of events with dateCreated field storing new MongoDate() as

```
"dateCreated": ISODate("2013-11-13T05: 23: 45.0Z")
```

Now I want one of the event created today. For this I was trying with query in yii framework as

```
$db->event->findOne(array('dateCreated' => new MongoDate()));
```

But it return null which I guess due to failing in comparing time values stored within dateCreated. So can any one suggest how to compare only date not time with MongoDate().

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To query for something created today, you'll want to use the Mongo `$gt` and `$lt` operators to search for a dateCreated key within the bounds of "today" in PHP:

```
$db->event->findOne(array('dateCreated' => array('$gt' => new MongoDate(strtotime("midnight")), '$lt' => new MongoDate(strtotime("11:59PM")))));
```

Comment: thanks, it works for me. Also there is a missing bracket in the above query. You may be edit it like below 

    $db->event->findOne(array('dateCreated' => array('$gt' => new MongoDate(strtotime("midnight")), '$lt' => new MongoDate(strtotime("11:59PM")))));

Answer (score 0):

This returns null because you are searching for a collection which was created just right now.

You have too look for [range queries with date.](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/)

So you need to modify it like this:

```
$db->event->findOne(
  array('dateCreated' => array(
    '$gte' => timestamp of the current day
  ))
);
```

As far as I understood you can find timestamp of a current day this way:

```
mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n'), date('j'));
```

but I might be wrong on this part.